# Tensorboard: No dashboards are active for the current data set

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I run Tensorboard from local with:

```
tensorboard --port 8080 --logdir gs://root-album-8512/output/summaries/ --debug
```

and then I access:

```
http://arynas:8080/
```

I got this error message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p7p3.png)

In my local terminal there is error like that:

```
tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/retrying_utils.cc:77] The operation failed and will be automatically retried in 1.15606 seconds (attempt 1 out of 10), caused by: Unavailable: Error executing an HTTP request (HTTP response code 0, error code 35, error message 'Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.googleapis.com:443 ')
         when reading gs://root-album-8512/output/summaries/train/../checkpoint
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The message looks clear enough. What do you have inside your summaries folder?

Answer (score 0):

> Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.googleapis.com:443

This error can be returned in case of exceeding the [request quota](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas).
Reportedly, this also can be [IPv6 issue](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/issues/94#issuecomment-170480087) on your `arynas` host.